# How can I change file encoding of the redirect file in a Windows batch script?

Tags: windows, encoding, batch-file

I have the following windows batch command as part of a larger batch file:

```
type *.sql > dbScript.txt
ren dbScript.txt dbScript.sql
```

As you can see it joins all SQL scripts in a particular directory into one so that it can be executed during the database build process.

My problem is that I now have non ANSI characters in one of the SQL script files but dbScript.txt (and subsequently dbScript.sql) are being encoded as ANSI.

How can I change the encoding of the output file to UTF-8?

Answer (score 3):

You'd have to run a program like [`iconv`](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libiconv.htm) to convert your output file. `cmd` only supports either the OEM codepage (by default) or UTF-16 (with the `/u` argument to `cmd`) as output encodings.

Alternatively, if the encoding problems are introduced because you are `type`ing the files and redirecting the output, you can also try something like the following, which should retain encodings (as it doesn't output and then write the text again):

```
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set LIST=NUL
for %%f in (*.sql) do set LIST=!LIST!+%%f
copy %LIST% dbScript.sql
endlocal
```

This would first generate a plus-separated list of SQL files and then use copy to concatenate them.

Comment: Doesn't need to. In that case we're at a point where immediate expansion doesn't hurt. But yes, it would work as well. It's only necessary that the `set` command in the `for` loop uses !LIST! because we need delayed expansion there.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried just using `copy`?

```
copy *.sql dbscript.sql
```